# Logic Beginner Question to Inferences

Tags: logic

I was trying to make sense of this book which discusses derivable arguments. It states that for the following text "each line is given a justification for why it is true in terms of previous lines and rules of inference."  How does addition, Modus Ponens, and Modus Tollens lead to the conditional statement for the negation of R? I do not see how these inferences are related.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

[image]       (3) Addition

[image]             (1), (4), Modus Ponens

[image]              (2),  (5),   Modus Tollens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition (from $A$ infer $A\vee B$) tells you that from (3) you can infer (4). Modus ponenes (from $A$ and $A\to B$ infer $B$) obviously gives you (5) from (1) and (4). And finally modus tollens (from $A\to B$ and $\neg B$ infer $\neg B$) aplied to (5) and (2) gives you (6). Does this put some light into your question? Or perhaps can you specify it bit more?

Edit: All of there infernce rules are actually schemes of rule. So in behalf of $A$ and $B$ you can take any proposition and the inference still holds. This is actually a nature of logical conference; it is only about the form of the argument. It might help you to substitute some real life propositions form the term. So in particular in derivation of (4) you know $C$ and you also know that from $C$ you can infer $C\vee E$. Which also amount to application of modus ponens to $C, C\to C\vee E$.

(1)-(3) are your assumptions. For example let $C$ stands for 'He has already eaten his breakfast'. If you take this proposition as true, you would agree that 'He has already eaten his breakfest or got divorced' is also true. This is how the addition rule work. Try to think about the other rules similarly.

Comment: I am confused with the from and infer part. I don't know how/if you substitute these inferences. For example in the addition inference you have p->pVq or q->pVq, yet I don't see anything before (CVE) to use this inference. Is there anyway you could explain just the addition part with more steps? I'm sure I could probably finish it once I get the first step.